# I cant get my code to draw a number pattern with nested loops in Python that will align all number printouts in a neat manner

Tags: python, nested-loops

Use nested for loops to create the following printout:

[image]

The number of rows should be read from the user. Use formatted printouts
so that the numbers are aligned even for two-digit numbers.
• All printed numbers correspond to column numbers.
• No number is printed if the column number is less than the row number.
• Print a suitable number of spaces to fill an empty column.

```
# Program to print a pattern with numbers

print("Program to print a pattern with numbers ")
print("-" * 50)
n = int(input("Please enter the number of rows "))
print("-" * 50)

for i in range(n + 1):
    # Increase triangle hidden
    for j in range(i):
        print(" ", end=' ')
    #  Decrease triangle to include numbers in pattern not in increment
    for j in range(i, n):
        print(j + 1, end=" ")
    print()
```

The code above produces the required output but the numbers are not aligned in an input with 2 digits. How do I format the iterables to make a perfectly aligned output printout.

Output:
[image]

Comment: I am new to programming, I would not know how to implement the function you mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you might modify your code to use `str.rjust`. Adjust the `2` in `rjust(2)` to whatever number you want.

```
print("Program to print a pattern with numbers ")
print("-" * 50)
n = int(input("Please enter the number of rows "))
print("-" * 50)

for i in range(n + 1):
    # Increase triangle hidden
    for j in range(i):
        print(" ".rjust(2), end="  ")
    #  Decrease triangle to include numbers in pattern not in increment
    for j in range(i, n):
        print(str(j+1).rjust(2), end="  ")
    print()
```

For your example, this gives:

```
Program to print a pattern with numbers 
--------------------------------------------------
Please enter the number of rows 12
--------------------------------------------------
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
     2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
         3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
             4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
                 5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
                     6   7   8   9  10  11  12  
                         7   8   9  10  11  12  
                             8   9  10  11  12  
                                 9  10  11  12  
                                    10  11  12  
                                        11  12  
                                            12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.rjust` to right-justify a string.  As long as you know the overall length of each line, that makes it easy to align each line so that they're all aligned on the right:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> for i in range(1, n+1):
...     print(''.join(str(j).rjust(3) for j in range(i, n+1)).rjust(n*3))
...
  1  2  3  4  5
     2  3  4  5
        3  4  5
           4  5
              5
```